# Seeking online resources to do collateral research on Internet?

Tags: research-methods, historical-context

I'm sure that genealogists know what collateral research, the study of family members, along with members of the ancestor's community, is.  However, I do not know of any online resources that use collateral research.

Where are the best online sources are to chart collateral research?

Comment: Hi Christopher - I'm a little confused by what your question is. You do research on collateral lines the same as you would for any ancestor, using the same resources and websites. By charting collateral research do you mean linking unrelated but "connected" people like neighbours, employers, etc.?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for evidence based software? http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/177/19

Comment: Hi Christopher, I'm still quite confused by what you are asking for here. Does the answer by @lkessler provide the types of resources you are looking for (one-place studies)?

Answer (score 6):

If you are interested in studying the members of an ancestor's community, then you should use the resources of two societies:

[The Society for One-Place-Studies](http://one-place-studies.org/). They have a blog, a Facebook group and a Twitter feed.

[One-Place Studies](http://www.oneplacestudy.org/). They also have a blog (called Latest News) and a Twitter feed.

As opposed to pure genealogical research, these organizations promote the study of places more so for the purpose of social science. The participants go through town registers listing births, marriages and deaths to put together the relationships and social history of a whole town.

These societies provide information and resources and other people doing similar community research with whom you can learn from and share techniques.